# Dynamic Configuration Management - Micro Service Architecture

Tags: java, python, configuration, architecture, microservices

I am looking for the Microservice Architecture (Say Approximately 30 services are available) including configuration service as one of the service which will have the responsibility to maintain the configurations for remaining 29 services. 
So that when I update the configuration, it needs to broadcast to all the remaining 29 services correspondingly.

I see this Architecture (https://dzone.com/articles/dynamic-configuration-management-in-microservice-a) is not a Dynamic Configuration Management, Here when I make the change in the configuration file, It is identified by the configuration service (Spring Cloud Service) from the GIT hook - TILL THIS IT IS A NICE IDEA

but then client services are responsible for refreshing the data from the configuration service, Here how does the client services know that the configuration is changed? Only the configuration service knows the configuration change from the GIT Hook.

(i.e)

1) User Manually change the configuration in Git and commit it
2) GIT HOOK notifies the configuration change to the configuration service

Expected :

3) then I feel that configuration service should notify all the clients to update the configuration from configuration service

Actual :

3) Instead, we need to manually trigger the client services with /refresh API for updating the configuration from the configuration services

So Is there a way for the configuration service to automatically update the configurations to the client services (i.e) It will be the dynamic-configuration-management.

Thanks,
Coder

Comment: There are a bunch of different ways you could handle dynamic configuration. You could you something like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) or [aws parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) to keep parameters. Your application can then determine how to consume them. That could be on startup or before each request

Comment: @badger0053 Good Day, to make it clear, when I edit my configuration files, I have my configuration changes in one of the service (i.e) configuration service, I need to boradcast this to the other services...

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating a service name [mhconfig](https://github.com/Gonlo2/mhconfig) that takes care of just that, you have a series of files, with the possibility of applying overrides, that the service provides through a gRPC API and you can both obtain or subscribe to it. It doesn't yet support both a java client and a git repository, but it's easily extrapolated using the python client and the inotify watcher as references so I encourage you in case it meets your requirements to improve it.